# How to translate `void(*fn)(const char *, ...)` to `std::function` and vice versa

Tags: c++, function, lambda, variadic-functions

```
typedef void(*fn1)(const char *, ...);
typedef std::function<void(const char *, ...)> fn2; // has initializer but incomplete type
```

Intuitively, these are the effectively the same to me, but obviously my intuition is failing me. How would I reconcile these data types?

1. How is `fn2` an incomplete type?
2. What changes are necessary to the signature of `fn2`, to allow me to assign it a type of `fn1`?
3. When creating a lambda to assign to `fn2`, how do I access the variadic argument list?

   In other words, what is the lambda equivalent to the following?

   ```
   void fn1_compatible (const char * format, ...) {
     va_list args;
     va_start(args, format);
     //TODO: Do stuff with variadic arguments
     va_end(args);
   }
   ```

> ***NOTE:** As an aside, these signatures are related to logging, but please answer the question in a general (not logging) context.*

Comment: Sounds like you should build a dedicated functor instead of using a `std::function`.  You can give the functor a variadic `operator()`

Comment: Are you saying it is not possible in C++?

Comment: AFAIK `void(...)` isn't a valid type for a template.

Comment: As I understand it, C-style variadic functions are a _runtime_ construct, where the arguments have no type information and their number can't be known at compile time. Modern C++ requires all types _and_ the number of arguments to be known before you call a function.

Comment: @alterigel, C++, modern or not, is backward compatible with its previous versions as well as C89 (almost), so you definitely can use and define C-style variadic functions in C++ (I mean you can use printf() in C++, right?). The only reason this doesn't work is because there is no `std::function` specialization that looks like this `template<class Ret, class... Args>
class function<Ret(Args..., ...)>`.

Comment: Logging in C++ shouldn’t ever be done like that. End of story right there. There’s precisely 0 reason to do it this way. None. Zip. Zilch. Nada.

Comment: Agreed. Except for maintaining compatibility with legacy code.

Answer (score 3):

Variadic functions are not supported by `std::function`. [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) takes one type, and it looks something like this:

```
template<class>
class function;  // Intentionally incomplete

template<class Ret, class... Args>
class function<Ret(Args...)> {
    // Deduce return type and argument types from function type
};
```

But this does not deduce the types for variadic function. So `void(const char*)` would work (`Ret` is `void` and `Args...` is `const char*`), but `void(const char*, ...)` would not work (As that would need to be deduced from `Ret(Args..., ...)`)

To make a functor object out of it, either just use a bare function pointer, like you did with `fn1`, or make do what the C standard library does with functions like [`vprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/vfprintf):

```
decltype(auto) my_variadic_function(const char * format, ...) {
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, format);
  try {
      auto&& return_value = vmy_variadic_function(format, args);
  } catch (...) {
      va_end(args);
      throw;
  }
  va_end(args);
  return std::forward<decltype(return_value)>(return_value);
}

void vmy_variadic_function(const char* format, va_list args) {
    // Do stuff with args
}
```

And then pass `vmy_variadic_function` in a `std::function<void(const char*, va_list)>`.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you cannot.

If you can alter your premise a bit. That is; instead of using for example `printf`, you could use `vprintf`. Then you could have:

```
using fn2 = std::function<int(const char*, va_list)>;
fn2 fun = vprintf;
```

You can then provide a wrapper function to call a `fn2` with `...` arguments:

```
int fun_wrapper(const char *format, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    int ret = fun(format, args);
    va_end(args);
    return ret;
}
```

*Usually* `...` functions are just wrappers for the `va_list` alternative that contains the actual implementation. Just like the shown `fun_wrapper`  is a wrapper for `fun`.

But if the `...` function that you want to use doesn't have `va_list` list version, and isn't implemented by you, then your best alternative might be to use something else.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, there's no way to map a C-style variadic list of arguments to a strongly-typed C++ function. It's possible to go the other way though, and it's possible to do this really safely.

Here, I've written a function `forward_to_variadic_fn` that accepts a C-style variadic function and a list of strongly-typed arguments. Variadic arguments have lots of [restrictions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments) about correct usage, so I decided to implement some safety checks that enforce these restrictions at compile time. For example, using this forwarding function, you can't accidentally pass a `std::string` when you should be passing a `const char*`

```
// true if T is trivially copy & move constructible and trivially destructible
template<typename T>
constexpr bool trivial_class = (std::is_trivially_copy_constructible_v<T> && std::is_trivially_move_constructible_v<T> && std::is_trivially_destructible_v<T>);

// true if T is acceptable for C-style va_args
template<typename T>
constexpr bool safe_for_va_args = (std::is_null_pointer_v<T> || std::is_pointer_v<T> || std::is_arithmetic_v<T> || std::is_member_pointer_v<T> || trivial_class<T>);

// true if all of Args.. are safe for C-style va_args
template<typename... Args>
constexpr bool all_safe_for_va_args = (true && ... && safe_for_va_args<std::decay_t<Args>>);

template<typename Ret, typename... Args>
Ret forward_to_variadic_fn(Ret(*the_fn)(const char*, ...), const char* format, Args... args){
    static_assert(all_safe_for_va_args<Args...>, "The provided types are not safe for use with C-style variadic functions.");
    return the_fn(format, args...);
}

int main(){
    
    int n = forward_to_variadic_fn(std::printf, "Hello, %s!\n", "world");
    std::cout << n << " characters were written.\n";
    
    std::string mystr = "world!";
    
    // This will compile but is BAD
    // std::printf("Hello, %s!\n", mystr);

    // The following line will not compile, which is a good thing!
    // forward_to_variadic_fn(std::printf, "Hello, %s!\n", mystr);

    // This is safe
    n = forward_to_variadic_fn(std::printf, "Hello, %s!\n", mystr.c_str());
    std::cout << n << " characters were written.\n";
    
    return 0;
}
```

[Live example here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e3b3e466ac595384)

Of course, this can't save you from using incorrect formatting flags, but it could save you from lots of other undefined behavior.

**Edit** for explanation: the helper template variable `all_safe_for_va_args` serves to enforce the restrictions on arguments to variadic functions as explained on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments):

> When a variadic function is called, after lvalue-to-rvalue, array-to-pointer, and function-to-pointer conversions, each argument that is a part of the variable argument list undergoes additional conversions known as default argument promotions:
>
> - `std::nullptr_t` is converted to `void*`
> - `float` arguments are converted to `double` as in floating-point promotion
> - `bool`, `char`, `short`, and unscoped enumerations are converted to `int` or wider integer types as in integer promotion
>
> Only arithmetic, enumeration, pointer, pointer to member, and class type arguments are allowed (except class types with non-trivial copy constructor, non-trivial move constructor, or a non-trivial destructor, which are conditionally-supported with implementation-defined semantics)

These individual conditions are neatly captured by the many helper traits classes and helper template variables in the [`<type_traits>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) library. For example, [`std::is_null_pointer_v<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_null_pointer) is a compile-time constant that evaluates to `true` if and only if `T` is `nullptr_t`.

The variable template `safe_for_va_args<T>` checks these requirements exhaustively and thus is true whenever the type `T` satisfies the above conditions. To make a variable template for this same condition that accepts any number of types, I used a [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) to efficiently do a logical AND over a parameter pack expansion, which can be seen in the implementation of `all_safe_for_va_args<T>`.

For example, `all_safe_for_va_args<int, nullptr, const char*>` evaluates to:

```
(true && safe_for_va_args<int> && safe_for_va_args<nullptr> && safe_for_va_args<const char*>)
```

all of which are `true`, so the whole expression is true.

This combines nicely with a [`static_assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert), which checks a custom condition at compile time, and can provide a user-friendly error message rather than a cryptic chain of template substitution failures.

In general, the types you're allowed to pass to a C-style variadic function are exclusively types that can be copied bit-for-bit and don't need any special maintenance. `std::string` fails this because it must perform memory allocations and deallocations, and so has neither a trivial constructor nor destructor. A `const char*` or `int` on the other hand can safely be copied bit-for-bit and considered logically identical.

Comment: This is brilliant! You clearly have a deep knowledge of types in C++. Can you break each step down with more comments (either in the code or in the solution itself)?

Comment: @Zak Thanks! I've updated my answer to include some explanation. Let me know if something else isn't clear

Comment: You could drop the "`true &&`" if you wanted: a unary fold expression using `&&` is true when the expanded pack(s) has zero elements.

Answer (score 0):

The lambda form for varargs is a straightforward conversion of the standalone function form.

```
auto thing = [](const char * format, ...) {
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, format);
  //TODO: Do stuff with variadic arguments
  va_end(args);
};
```

This is accepted by G++.

Unfortunately clang seems to have a bug where it doesn't recognize that its `__builtin__vastart` keyword is being used inside a lambda with variable argument list.

Comment: Caveat: This can neither be stored in a `std::function`, nor be converted to a function pointer.