# Why isn't it a compile error if you pass a class object to scanf?

Tags: c++

Why is the code below accepted by g++?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

int main()
{
   std::string str;
   scanf("%s", str);
}
```

What sense does it make to pass a class object to `scanf()`? Does it get converted to anything that could be useful to another function with variadic arguments?

Comment: If you pass a wrong type to `scanf` (e.g.: a `char` instead of a `int`) it's not a compile error either, it just invokes *undefined behavior* - C functions using variadic arguments have no type checking in them

Comment: What error were you expecting? Also, can you clarify "class object"? Many languages (Ruby, Java, for example) have class objects (instances of class Class) but I don't think C++ does.

Comment: To clarify: is your question “why does the C++ language not disallow this?,” or “why doesn’t g++ warn about this?”

Comment: You can pass literally anything to scanf function, but if it doesn't match the format string, you get undefined behaviour. That's why you should be using C++ extractors instead (e.g. `std::cin`)

Comment: @RayToal The C++ standard speaks of `objects of class type`, i.e. instances of some class/struct/union. I think that's close enough to `class objects`.

Comment: @templatetypedef I wanted to know "why does the C++ language not disallow this".

Comment: @RayToal an object whose type is a class, unlike primitive types, arrays, pointers, etc.

Comment: @UnholySheep "*C functions using variadic arguments have no type checking in them*" - actually, several modern C++ compilers DO offer compile-time checking for printf-style and scanf-style functions

Comment: As an aside, you can use template parameter packs to do some automated type checking and prevent exactly this kind of mistake at compile time. See this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55423225/how-to-translate-voidfnconst-char-to-stdfunction-and-vice-vers/55424089#55424089

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scanf` comes from `C`. In `C` if you wanted to have variable number of arguments (like `scanf` needs) the only solution was [variadic function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic). Variadic functions by design are not type safe, i.e. you can pass absolutely any type and a varargs function will happily accept them. It is a limitation of the C language. That doesn't mean that any type is valid. If an type other than what is actually expected is passed, then we are in the wonderful land of Undefined Behavior.

That being said, `scanf` is a standard function and what it can accept is known, so most compilers will do extra checks (not required by the standard) if you enable the right flags. See Neil's answer for that.

In C++ (since C++11) we have [parameter packs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) which are type safe ...ish (oh, concepts cannot get sooner).

Comment: I guess I'm doing a poor job with my question. What I'm really surprised is that you can pass a struct to a variadic function. There is *some* type verification... floats are promoted, and so are integers smaller than `int`. So why does it accept a struct? Is there any use for it?

Comment: @giusti, It's reasonable to want to pass structs in your own variadic functions. The language can't really disallow that as a whole just for the sake of `printf` and `scanf`. The other rules you mention are things baked into the language (as opposed to `printf` and `scanf`) that can apply well enough to all variadic functions.

Comment: That's true, Stroustrup made it a design goal, IIRC, to make user types, such as structs, able to behave just like the built in types! So disallowing structs and other user types in variadic functions, would be, IMHO, contrary to the language philosophy.

Comment: @RayToal - while, yes, a design goal of C++ was to allow user-types to behave (a lot) like built-in types -  variadic functions were inherited from C, and predate C++ entirely.  C allows variadic functions to accept arguments of any type, including struct types and pointer types, and so does C++.   `scanf()` only supports the types that be represented in the format string - and there are no format specifiers that represent any struct types.

Answer (score 3):

Enable some warnings.  With `-Wextra -Wall -pedantic`, you will get:

```
a.cpp:7:10: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char*', but argument 2 has    type 'std::__cxx11::string' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'} [-Wformat=]
scanf("%s", str);
```

If you want that to be an error rather than a warning, add `-Werror`.

Answer (score 1):

To answer each of your questions...

1. The question in the title: "Why isn't it a compile error if you pass a class object to scanf?"

Because the declaration of `scanf` is `int scanf ( const char * format, ... );` which means it will accept any number of arguments after the format string as [variadic arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments). The rules for such arguments are:

> When a variadic function is called, after lvalue-to-rvalue, array-to-pointer, and function-to-pointer conversions, each argument that is a part of the variable argument list undergoes additional conversions known as default argument promotions:
>
> - std::nullptr_t is converted to void*
> - float arguments are converted to double as in floating-point promotion
> - bool, char, short, and unscoped enumerations are converted to int or wider integer types as in integer promotion
>
> Only arithmetic, enumeration, pointer, pointer to member, and class type arguments are allowed (except class types with non-trivial copy constructor, non-trivial move constructor, or a non-trivial destructor, which are conditionally-supported with implementation-defined semantics)

Since `std::string` is a class type with non-trivial copy and move constructors, passing the argument is not allowed. Interestingly, this prohibition, while checkable by a compiler, is not rejected by the compiler as an error.

2. The first question in the body: "Why is the code below accepted by g++?"

That is a great question. The other answer by @LightnessRacesInOrbit addresses this point very well.

3. Your second question in the body: "Does it get converted to anything that could be useful to another function with variadic arguments?"

If you run the code, one of the possible results (at run time) is:

```
.... line 5: 19689 Segmentation fault      (core dumped)
```

so, no, it is not converted into anything, in general, at least not implicitly.

4. The clarifying question in the comment thread to the question: "I wanted to know "why does the C++ language not disallow this"".

This question appears to be a subjective one, touching on why the C++ language designer(s) and perhaps even the C language designers, did not make their language design robust enough for the language definition to prohibit something other than a string, or memory buffer, or any number of other things, to be sensible as a non-initial argument to `scanf`. What we do know is that a compiler can often determine such things (that's what linters do, after all!) but we can only guess, really. My guess is that in order to make `scanf` super typesafe (in the language definition, as opposed to needing a linter) they would need to redefine `scanf` to use template arguments of some sort. However `scanf` comes from C, so they did not want to change its signature (that would indeed be wrong, given that C++ wants to be a C superset...).

Comment: Your point 1 isn't quite right; it seems to suggest that the call itself is fine but that the semantics of `scanf` make it UB. That is not true. Passing the string through varargs is where the UB begins. From cppreference: _"Only arithmetic, enumeration, pointer, pointer to member, and class type arguments are allowed (except class types with non-trivial copy constructor, non-trivial move constructor, or a non-trivial destructor, which are conditionally-supported with implementation-defined semantics)"_

Comment: Point taken, saying "any type whatsoever" was wrong and I have edited, but as far as whether or not the argument is acceptable, isn't the OP's expression `str` an expression of a [class type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type)? And aren't `std::string`'s constructors trivial?

Comment: How can `std::string`'s ctors be trivial? Think about what they have to do.

Comment: I need to step. away. from. the. keyboard. now. Fixed and thank you.

Comment: I actually do agree that it's a bit weird that varargs aren't more harshly diagnosed. My guess: low priority, no real point changing it

Answer (score 1):

You have two distinct problems here, not just one:

1. The passing of a `std::string` through variadic arguments (which has undefined behaviour), and
2. The passing of a `std::string` to a function whose logical semantics expected a `char*` instead (which has undefined behaviour).

So, no, it doesn't make sense. But it's not a hard error. If you're asking *why* this has undefined behaviour rather than being ill-formed (and requiring a hard error), I do not know specifically but the answer is *usually* that it was deemed insufficiently important to require compilers to go to the trouble it would take to diagnose it.

Also, it would be unusual for a logical precondition violation to be deemed ill-formed (just as a matter of convention and consistency; many such violations could not be detected before runtime), so I'd expect point #2 to have undefined behaviour regardless of what hypothetical changes we made to the language to better reject cases of point #1.

Anyway, in the twenty years since standardisation, we've reached a point in technology where the mainstream toolchains do warn on it anyway, and since warnings can be turned into errors, it doesn't really matter.